# Not able to receive notification on android device using Parse.com push notification service

Tags: parse-platform

I am not able to receive notification on android device. I am seeing following error message on app startup.

Could not find method android.database.Cursor.getNotificationUri, referenced from method com.parse.ParseSQLiteCursor.getNotificationUri

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If your code was similar to old code in parse sample code like above.

```
// Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, SavedVideoListActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Try to choose this code in new sample code. (https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was missing correct permission in manifest file.